# Why is my JS variable not being seen outside of jquery.each() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Edit: ***I have since figured out the issue with the help of the other users that commented below.***
The issue is that using jQuery.load() has a lag time. And as pointed out below, the problem was the variable was seen, just not the data within it. My solution to the below problem was adjust the code slightly using [jquery's deferred object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) functions.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'koc-click-tracker-loader.php',
    data: {url: 'ar'},
    dataType: 'html',
    context: document.body })
.done( function( data ) {
    // Same functionality as below
    });
```

**Original Post:**
I am trying to parse an HTML table with 7 columns

> Rank | Username | Highest CPM | Last 24h | Total clicks | Links Left | Last Clicked

Then I'm trying to put each row's data into a JSON object. However, when I try to access the data outside of the .each() loop, I can not. My variable is defined in the global scope. When I try to, for debugging sake, alert(output[1](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).Rank).

```
var output = [];
$(function(){
    var output = [];
    $("#_BLANK").load("koc-click-tracker-loader.php #ar_content table", { url: 'ar' }, function() {
        var data = $("#_BLANK table tbody"); i=0;
        data.find('tr').each( function() {
            var $td = $(this).find('td');

            if ( i > 0 ) { // Skip first iteration, has blank data.
            output[i] = {
                Rank: $td.eq(0).text(),
                User: $td.eq(1).text(),
                KocID: $td.eq(1).find('a').prop("href"),
                CPM: $td.eq(2).text(),
                Last24: $td.eq(3).text(),
                TotalClick: $td.eq(4).text(),
                LinksLeft: $td.eq(5).text(),
                LastClicked: $td.eq(6).text() };
                }
            i++;
            });
        // Will Error here as well.
        });
    alert(output[1].Rank); // Errors here.
    console.log("output", output); // Shows all the data properly.
    });
```

> Cannot read property 'Rank' of undefined.

Again, for some reason, my variable isn't global. Or there is something I'm missing something with jQuery...

Comment: `alert(output[0].Rank);` gives an error because your `output[0]` element is `undefined` - you deliberately skip index 1 in your loop.

Comment: In this case, that is correct. Typo on my part. 1 or more still error.

Comment: In that case it would seem to be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?noredirect=1&lq=1) and quite a few others. Note that it isn't telling you that `output` is undefined, it is telling you that `output[1]` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your $.each() function is inside a $.load() function.

The load function is an async call. You are in a race condition.

I bet if you put a break point on the `output[i] = {` line, and also on the `alert(output[0].Rank);` line, you will hit the alert first.

Comment: It's not really a "race condition" in the sense of a situation where the timing of the outcome can't be determined in advance. We know the `.load()` callback will *definitely* run after the other code runs.

Comment: yes, and he is trying to access an attribute on an object that doesn't exist yet, hence the error.

Comment: Whoa... There was a lot more to this issue then I realized.